# Remix Transaction Execution Failed

Tags: remix, ether

I tried to upload this on the matic mainnet but it keeps failing

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract chibichangas is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
  using Strings for uint256;

  string public baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost = 0.02 ether;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 20;
  bool public paused = false;

  constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);

    mint(msg.sender, 20);
  }

  // internal
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseURI;
  }

  // public
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(!paused);
    require(_mintAmount > 0);
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
      require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
    }

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
    }
  }

  function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory)
  {
    uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
    uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
    for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
      tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
    }
    return tokenIds;
  }

  function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
    public
    view
    virtual
    override
    returns (string memory)
  {
    require(
      _exists(tokenId),
      "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
    );

    string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
    return
      bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
        ? string(
          abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension)
        )
        : "";
  }

  //only owner
  function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner() {
    cost = _newCost;
  }

  function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner() {
    maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
  }

  function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
    baseURI = _newBaseURI;
  }

  function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension) public onlyOwner {
    baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
  }

  function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    paused = _state;
  }

  function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    require(payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance));
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to format the code and specify the error you are getting. Under which circumstances is failing? Just the deploy? Please follow the guidelines to improve question quality

Comment: How does it fail? What function were you calling? What's the exact error message? Can you try a different network?